# Circular progress button automatically trigger once the progress is complete

Tags: dart, flutter

I have a working circular progress button based ontapdown and ontapup, however i wanted it to trigger once the progress complete. Right now it only trigger only when the progress is complete and user tapUp.

[image: This is the one i manage to do]

```
onTapDown: (_) {
controller1.forward();
},

onTapUp: (_) {
  if (controller1.status ==
      AnimationStatus.forward) {
    controller1.reverse();
  } else if (controller1.status ==
      AnimationStatus.completed) {
    setState(() {
      controller1.value = 0.0;
      // widget.isClickCALLBOMBA = true;
      // controller1.reverse();
      Flushbar()
        ..title = allTranslations
            .text('success')
        ..message =
            "We will alert the bomba !"
        ..duration =
            Duration(seconds: 3)
        ..backgroundColor =
            Colors.red
        ..show(context);
    });
  }
},
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a listener to your `AnimationController` to do stuff when the animation is complete:

```
controller1.addStatusListener((status) {
  if (status != AnimationStatus.completed) {
    return;
  }

  //Animation is complete! Do completion stuff.
});
```